# How to reset my bluetooth stack? (ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 16.10, headphones

Out of the box, my laptop's Bluetooth worked well enough (not perfect, mind you: I had to install blueman and tweak a little around). I was able to pair my headphones (I have several different devices). However, as the installationa matured and I installed more stuff on my computer, at some point (I don't know when), My headphones cannot connect anymore. In blueman, I can see the connection attempt, and it fails.

Before trying to investigate and diagnose this specific case (I have tried to follow many related issues on the forums all over the internet and askubuntu, without success), I would like to try to just reset the whole thing. Uninstall everything, delete any custom configuration that may exist, and install again. If this works, I'll avoid a ton of pain. I think it is worth a shot.

Anyone knows how I can do this?

Thanks